# Variable in git command substitution changes w.r.t directory

Tags: bash, git

I'm assigning a git command result to a variable using command substitution. I expect the value of the variable will be static when using it at a later part of the bash script. However, when I change the directory the output from echo becomes different. Why the value of the variable is not static?

```
test@ubuntu:/tmp/test1$ result=$(git branch -a)

test@ubuntu:/tmp/test1$ echo $result
master.txt master test_branch1 test_branch2

test@ubuntu:/tmp/test1$ cd ..

test@ubuntu:/tmp$ echo $result
config-err-K2fmPh test1 tracker-extract-files.1001 tracker-extract-files.126 vscode-typescript1001 master test_branch1 test_branch2 remotes/origin/maste remotes/origin/test_branch1 remotes/origin/test_branch2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because one of the tokens that `git branch -a` returns is a lone `*`.

When you

```
echo $result
```

instead of

```
echo "$result"
```

the `*` causes file name expansion. For this reason, you see `master.txt` in the first output, which, I guess, is not a branch name, but a file name in the directory.

For the same reason, you see a lot of files listed when you step into a different directory.

If you do not want `*` to expand, you must use

```
echo "$result"
```

But this will show the `*` literally in the output, of course.